# Debugger disconnects when debugging the Parse quickstart project on Texas Instruments CC3200 LaunchPad

Tags: parse-platform, texas-instruments

I followed the parse quick start guide for CC3200 [here](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#embedded/ticc3200). Running the Release binary on the device works well.

I then tried to debug the program from CCS. However, the debugger disconnects from the board pretty quickly with the following output in the CCS console:

```
Cortex_M4_0: Can't Single Step Target Program: Debug Port error occurred.
Cortex_M4_0: Error 
Cortex_M4_0: Unable to determine target status after 20 attempts
```

It happens when the last line in `PinMuxConfig` is called:

```
MAP_PinTypeTimer(PIN_17, PIN_MODE_5);
```

It is important to mention that the code continues to run on the board, but there is no way to debug it.

When I comment out this line, the debugger does not disconnect.

I use CCS 6.1.0.00104, sevice pack 1.0.0.10.0.

I am looking for ideas why the debugger disconnects when using the original code.